# Can macro cause performance issues to Web applications

Tags: .net, vba, ms-access, networking, database-performance

I have created some macro project in my company which uses SQL queries to update the data into an Access database.

The database file is saved on a network drive. The user fills the VBA forms and the data gets transferred into the Access database using SQL queries .

Nowadays my team (around 269 members) are facing issue with the core business applications. The core business applications that I am talking about are built in .Net using MVC and is a Web application server side program.

Can my project which uses VBA +Access +network drive cause performance problems for the core business applications?

I noticed when with the growing use of my VBA tools the issue is increasing.

Comment: Apparently, if your app and  core business application are using the same hadware they can cause performance for the other one.

Comment: Thanks serg for quick comments.. Yes the apps run on the same machin but I have checked the system performance.. I mean ram utilization and process performance both looked fine to me.  In my understanding.... If I am running Facebook and at the same time if I running macro how can it hamper the performance.? Or is it the network drive?  Coz network drive and core applications can't have same server!apologies if I am making you confused!

Comment: It may be disk subsystem, networking ...